# Multi threading on JAVA

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jna

I am getting memory crash in the JVM multi threaded environment. In Each thread run environment I am loading an instance of the C++ shared library. (Say exm1.so, exm2.so etc).

Let me tell you first that the C++ shared library is not thread safe.  So we are loading each thread created by JVM with an instance of the C++ shared library. Java code :

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;

Thread 1:

run{
  x libraryInstance = Native.loadLibrary(exm1.so, x.class);
  x. mymethod();
}

Thread 2:

run{
  x libraryInstance = Native.loadLibrary(exm2.so, x.class);
  x. mymethod();
}
```

My question is in which memory this .so file will be stored and Is JVM manage each thread memory in a thread safe manner?

In each .so file has C++ malloc function calls. JVM manage this memory ptr effectively.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you have to manage safe multithreading by yourself, by mean of `synchronized` construct, to protect access to shared resources.

Comment: Can you tell me which memory .so will be loaded by JVM. Thread stack or Heap. If it is heap then is it thread safe the native .so file?

Comment: Not sure about that. Are you are getting the crash at lib loading time or calling time?

Answer (score 0):

To I got the correct answer. dlopen in Linux through JAVA is not defaulted with RTLD_LOCAL. I have passed explicitly the same. it worked.